# how to approach phrase queries and term grouping

Tags: java, lucene, indexing, tokenize

I am new to Lucene and my project is to provide specialized search for a set
of booklets. I am using Lucene Java 3.1.

The basic idea is to help people know where to look for information in the (rather
large and dry) booklets by consulting the index to find out what booklet and page numbers match their query. Each Document in my index represents a particular page in one of the booklets.

So far I have been able to successfully scrape the raw text from the booklets,
insert it into an index, and query it just fine using StandardAnalyzer on both
ends.

So here's my general question:
Many queries on the index will involve searching for place names mentioned in the
booklets. Some place names use notational variants. For instance, in the body text
it will be called "Ship Creek" on one page, but in a map diagram elsewhere it might be listed as "Ship Cr." or even "Ship Ck.". What I need to know is how to approach treating the two consecutive words as a single term and add the notational variants as synonyms.

My goal is of course to search with any of the variants and catch all occurrences. If I search for (Ship AND (Cr Ck Creek)) this does not give me what I want because other words may appear between [ship] and [cr]/[ck]/[creek] leading to false positives.

So, in a nutshell I probably still need the basic stuff provided by StandardAnalyzer, but with specific term grouping to emit place names as complete terms and possibly insert synonyms to cover the variants.

For instance, the text "...allowed from the mouth of Ship Creek upstream to ..." would
result in tokens [allowed],[mouth],[ship creek],[upstream]. Perhaps via a TokenFilter along
the way, the [ship creek] term would expand into [ship creek][ship ck][ship cr].

As a bonus it would be nice to treat the trickier text "..except in Ship, Bird, and
Campbell creeks where the limit is..." as [except],[ship creek],[bird creek],
[campbell creek],[where],[limit].

This seems like a pretty basic use case, but it's not clear to me how I might be able to use existing components from Lucene contrib or SOLR to accomplish this. Should the detection and merging be done in some kind of TokenFilter? Do I need a custom Analyzer implementation?

Some of the term grouping can probably be done heuristically [*],[creek] is [* creek]
but I also have an exhaustive list of places mentioned in the text if that helps.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Solr's [Synonym Filter.](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#SynonymFilter) Just set up "creek" to have synonyms "ck", "cr" etc.

I'm not aware of any existing functionality to solve your "bonus" problem.